# What is the time complexity of a function with two parameters?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the following method? Two parameters give me lots of confusion. Thanks in advance.

```
public int count(int m, int n) {
    if(m == 1 || n == 1) return 1;
    return count(m-1, n) + count(m, n-1);
}
```

Comment: O(N). The method is executed either m **or** n times, whichever is smaller.

Comment: I thought so as well at first, but not quite. Try working through `count(3, 3)` on paper, examining the calls as a binary tree. For `3, 3`, you get 11 calls (including the root).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's wrong. (How many times will count(1,1) invoked if you started with count(3,3)?)

Comment: Empirical testing puts it in the `O(2^(n+m))` range - `count(12, 12)` results in 1.41 million calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in `O(2^(n+m))`.

It can be proven using induction, where the induction step is:

```
T(n,m) = T(n-1,m) + T(n, m-1) =(*) 2^(n+m-1) + 2^(n+m-1) = 2*2^(n+m-1) = 2^(n+m)
```

Where (*) is the induciton hypothesis.